# Gradle can't find Lombok generated constructor in integration test

Tags: java, gradle, lombok, integration-testing

I have integration test that has inner class with `Lombok` annotations. It looks like this

```
@Test(dataProvider = "jsonDiff")
public class JaversDiffIntegrationTest {

    public void shouldCompareEntities(Person input1, Person input2, String expectedJson)
        throws JSONException {
        Person p1 = new Person("p_id", "Jack");
        Person p2 = new Person("p_id", "Michael");
        ....
    }

    @TypeName("TestEntityPerson")
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private class Person {
        private String id;
        private String name;
    }
```

In `Idea` I enabled annotation processing and at least it is able to compile. When I try to run `clean build` via `gradlew` I get the error

```
constructor Person in class JaversDiffIntegrationTest.Person cannot be applied to given types;
    Person p2 = new Person("p_id", "Michael");
                    ^
    required: no arguments
    found: String,String
```

It seems it doesn't see `lombok` generated constructors.
My `build.gradle` looks like this (I use `gradle5`)

```
apply plugin: 'idea'

// TODO: move to integration-test.gradle
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java.srcDir 'src/testInteg/java'
        resources.srcDir 'src/testInteg/resources'
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom implementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom runtimeOnly
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
    mustRunAfter test

    useTestNG() {
        suites 'src/testInteg/resources/testng.xml'
    }

    testLogging {
        showStandardStreams = true
    }
}

check.dependsOn integrationTest

dependencies {
    implementation "javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.Final"
    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.11"

    testImplementation "org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5"
    testImplementation "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.5.6"

    implementation "org.javers:javers-core:5.3.2"
    annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6"
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6"

    integrationTestImplementation "org.testng:testng:6.14.3"
    integrationTestImplementation "org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0"
    integrationTestImplementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5"
    integrationTestImplementation "commons-io:commons-io:2.6"
}
```

What is the problem? Maybe I have some issue with `integrationTest` configuration?

Comment: `@Data` should generate `NoArg` and `AllArg` constructors

Comment: I've had cases in the past where the getter and setter annotations didn't appear to be generating them. I ended up just writing them myself. These questions seem common with Lombok

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I believe the crucial bit that you are missing is an [annotation processor configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/5.3.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#java_source_set_configurations) for your `integrationTest` source set:

```
    integrationTestAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6"
```

---

In the following, you can find a self-contained, working example (tested with Gradle 5.3.1). It’s not exactly your project but should be close enough to get you on track:

#### `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
        java.srcDir 'src/testInteg/java'
        resources.srcDir 'src/testInteg/resources'
    }
}

configurations {
    integrationTestImplementation.extendsFrom testImplementation
    integrationTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom testRuntimeOnly
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath + sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
}

repositories {
    jcenter();
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6"

    testImplementation "junit:junit:4.11"

    integrationTestAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6"
}
```

#### `src/testInteg/java/MyTest.java`

```
public class MyTest {

  @org.junit.Test
  public void test() {
    new Person("foo", "bar");
    assert true;
  }

  @lombok.AllArgsConstructor
  private class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
  }
}
```

Comment: How to add visibility of classes in `main`? Because I don't have access to any class from the main.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply: unless you’ve found the answer already, I’d recommend to create a new question for that issue. Thanks!

Comment: I have found the solution

Comment: It's testAnnotationProcessor now.

Answer (score 19):

I also found the same issue and fixed by adding testAnnotationProcessor beside annotationProcessor to build.gradle:

```
annotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
testAnnotationProcessor "org.projectlombok:lombok:${lombok_version}"
```

Answer (score 10):

According to lombok ([lombok gradle](https://projectlombok.org/setup/gradle))

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.24'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was also required to add the following:

```
annotationProcessorPath += main.output + test.output
annotationProcessorPath += sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
```

to this section:

```
sourceSets {
    integrationTest {
       //here
    }
}
```